# iText7 ShowTextAligned vs MoveText

Tags: c#, itext7

I am updating the logic for my pdf tool and I am seeing some setting. In the old version I have this `overContent` that has a method `ShowTextAligned` with five values. The new object canvas has `MoveText` with just two. Is the below correct with the `MoveText` and `ShowTextAligned`

New Code

```
   float n2 = 15F;
   float n3 = pageSizeWithRotation.GetHeight() - 10F;
   
   canvas.BeginText() 
    .SetFillColorRgb(0,0,0)                                        
    .SetFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA), 7F)
    .MoveText(n2, n3)
    .ShowText(disclaimerText)
    .EndText();
```

Old Version

```
PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
overContent.BeginText();
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("Helvetica", "Cp1250", false);
overContent.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 7F);
overContent.SetRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
float n2 = 15F;
float n3 = pageSizeWithRotation.Height - 10F;

overContent.ShowTextAligned(0, disclaimerText, n2, n3, 0F);
```

Comment: See latest documentation (https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.2.1/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_canvas.html).  You need to adjust the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use document.ShowTextAligned() which is easier to work with Text and Paragraph in iText 7.

```
    public virtual void CreatePdf(String dest) {
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde");
        document.ShowTextAligned(title, 36, 806, TextAlignment.LEFT);
        Paragraph author = new Paragraph("by Robert Louis Stevenson");
        document.ShowTextAligned(author, 36, 806, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.TOP);
        document.ShowTextAligned("Jekyll", 300, 800, TextAlignment.CENTER, 0.5f * (float)Math.PI);
        document.ShowTextAligned("Hyde", 300, 800, TextAlignment.CENTER, -0.5f * (float)Math.PI);
        document.ShowTextAligned("Jekyll", 350, 800, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0.5f * (float)Math
            .PI);
        document.ShowTextAligned("Hyde", 350, 800, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, -0.5f * (float)Math
            .PI);
        document.ShowTextAligned("Jekyll", 400, 800, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0.5f * (float
            )Math.PI);
        document.ShowTextAligned("Hyde", 400, 800, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, -0.5f * (float)
            Math.PI);
        document.Close();
    }
```

Please refer to link https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/itext-7-building-blocks-chapter-2-rootelement-examples and example number c02e14_showtextaligned

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `ShowTextAligned` is not only defined for `Document` but already at `RootElement` level. Thus, in particular `Canvas` also offers `ShowTextAligned` functionality.

Comment: @mkl i dont see `ShowTextAligned` function in `canvas`

Comment: @Jefferson *"i dont see `ShowTextAligned` function in `canvas`"* - is your `canvas` an instance of the class `Canvas` or of the class `PdfCanvas`? I was talking about the class `Canvas`.

Comment: yes its a PdfCanvas

Comment: So that explains it.